# SQL - conditional WHERE

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am quite newbie in SQL, but I am quite sure about this one, which is suppose to work, but it does not! :-) Script is very easy, but I need to describe it first.

I have 2 tables - One table with Teacher Data (wp_user) and one with their student data (wp_results).

These two tables has one identificator - schoolid. What I am trying to do is easy work - display to a teacher according his schoolid all his/her students with the same school id.

```
              $teacher =  wp_get_current_user();       
       global $wpdb;

       $get_student = "SELECT 
       wp_results.WORLDPLACE,wp_results.EUPLACE,wp_results.CZPLACE 
       FROM wp_results 
       WHERE wp_results.SCHOOLID = $teacher->schoolid";


       $results_of_teachers_students = $wpdb->get_results($get_student);
       echo $results_of_teachers_students;

       foreach ($results_of_teachers_students as $value){
        echo '<tr><td>'.$value->WORLDPLACE.'</td>';
        echo '<tr><td>'.$value->EUPLACE.'</td>';
         echo '<tr><td>'.$value->CZPLACE.'</td>';
         }
```

These two line of codes just get and display teachers school id.

```
$teacher =  wp_get_current_user();
echo $teacher->schoolid;
```

This says: select WORLDPLACE, EUPLACE and CZPLACE from table called "wp_results" BUT only if teacher's schoold id (this ID is stored as a variable) equals schoolid from wp_results.

```
global $wpdb; 
   $get_student = ("SELECT 
   wp_results.WORLDPLACE,wp_results.EUPLACE,wp_results.CZPLACE FROM 
   wp_results WHERE wp_results.SCHOOLID = $teacher->schoolid");
```

And the rest of code is pretty clear: store all data to variable and print them as a table.

```
$results_of_teachers_students = $wpdb->get_results($get_student);
       foreach ($results_of_teachers_students as $value){
        echo '<tr><td>'.$value->WORLDPLACE.'</td>';
        echo '<tr><td>'.$value->EUPLACE.'</td>';
         echo '<tr><td>'.$value->CZPLACE.'</td>';
```

But I am not getting any results. Do you see what I do not? :-) Thank you in advance for your help :-)

Representation of wp_results table:

```
SCHOOLID    WORLDPLACE  EUPLACE CZPLACE FIRSTNAME   LASTNAME    EMAIL
```

Representation of wp_users table:

```
ID  user_login  user_pass  user_nicename  user_email  user_url  user_registered  user_activation_key  user_status  display_name
```

As you can see, in WP_users table there is no column "SCHOOLID" - this schoolid is in wp_usermeta, but who cares since I can call it as variable:

```
 $teacher =  wp_get_current_user();
       echo $teacher->schoolid;
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What returns `echo $get_student`?

Comment: It returns whole query as a string :O

Comment: I know, it should be. Are there variables/values as you expected? What about mysqli_error? What is `wp_results` table structure?

Comment: If SQL query is okay, then in `foreach` couldn't be a table name. Use `$value->WORLDPLACE` instead of `$value->wp_results.WORLDPLACE`.

Comment: http://www.jaroslavhuss.cz/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/aha.png

Comment: This is table structure...

Comment: I updated a code... still does not work :-X

Comment: It seems @panther, array is empty so query is wrong :X

Comment: try to take echoed string and put it directly into PMA or Adminer, if query run or return any error. It's basic SQL problem, hardly debugged from printscreens. You should be able to debug it yourself now.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in php variable inside SQL. This is correct code:

```
$teacher  =  wp_get_current_user();       
       global $wpdb;

       $get_student = "SELECT 
       wp_results.WORLDPLACE,wp_results.EUPLACE,wp_results.CZPLACE 
       FROM wp_results WHERE wp_results.SCHOOLID = '$teacher->schoolid'";


       $results_of_teachers_students = $wpdb->get_results($get_student);
           print_r($results_of_teachers_students);
       foreach ($results_of_teachers_students as $value){
        echo '<tr><td>'.$value->WORLDPLACE.'</td><td>'.$value->EUPLACE.'</td><td>'.$value->CZPLACE.'</td>';

      }
```

PHP variable needs to be in '' :D Lol, so much time...